# How to connect MQTT client using Adafruit IO in Android?

Tags: android, arduino

I'm working on an Android app. In this app I'm using an MQTT server to control home appliances with Wifi Home Automation. Backend team uses Adafruit IO for MQTT server connection. I'm not familiar with Adafruit IO and MQTT client-side code. Please help me with Adafruit IO MQTT APIs.

How can the background app connect to the server, register the device in Database?. Also fetch the IOT ID, key and feed returned from the server.

These details have to be fed to the device and also preserved. Using these details, the app will be able to subscribe and publish any updates related to the device.

Comment: which Mqtt server (broker)you are using?

Comment: Can please state your needs one by one.

Comment: On the Android side you can go with paho-eclipse library for this development

Comment: Adafruit IO server (broker) we can use

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentations

Adafruit IO is a system that makes data useful. Our focus is on ease of use, and allowing simple data connections with little programming required.

IO includes [client libraries](http://io.adafruit.com/api/docs/#!/v2) that wrap our REST and MQTT APIs. IO is built on Ruby on Rails, and Node.js.

MQTT, or message queue telemetry transport, is a protocol for device communication that Adafruit IO supports. Using an MQTT library or client you can publish and subscribe to a feed to send and receive feed data.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, you can use MQTT.fx software and install it on your PC.[MQTT.fx download](http://mqttfx.jensd.de/)

Get into the settings and give Broker Details(adafruitt.io) and give connect.So in MQTT your broker is the server and both publisher and subscriber are clients.Both Publisher and subscriber exchange data using topic names.

In Android, I can give you a sample code for MQTT client (publisher and subscriber)

1.Create Android client as given below
once a Client is created, specify the keep alive and time out of client with proper client ID.Suppose in your App if you want to publish and subscribe you can think about creating 2 instances of MQTT client.

```
              mpub = new MqttAndroidClient(context, 
              mqttBrokerURL, PublisherClientID, new MemoryPersistence())
              MqttConnectOptions options = null;
              options = new MqttConnectOptions();
              options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);
              options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
              options.setKeepAliveInterval(120);
              options.setCleanSession(true);
```

2. Fix your topics for publishing and subscribing ,Suppose if you have to publish you can set the payload.and then publish data.

   ```
   messagePublisher.setPayload((msg.toString()).getBytes());
   try {
        mpub.connect(options, new IMqttActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {

                   try {
                        mpub.publish(Topic, 
                      messagePublisher.getPayload(), Qos, retain);

                   } catch (MqttException | NullPointerException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

               }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken_p, Throwable 
          throwable) {

                   disconnect();
               }
           });

       } catch (MqttException | NullPointerException ex) {

       }
   ```

   // above code can be used for publishing data to client

3.For subscribing create a new MQTT client do all the general settings(keep 
alive, timeout, encryption, username, password) and finally set callback and 
implement MQTT callback to get the overriding functions.

```
// subscribe refer this method :
   SimpleClient(){
    try {
        client = new MqttClient(MQTT_BROKER, "myID");
        client.connect();
        client.setCallback(this);
        client.subscribe("my/subscription/topic");
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws 
  Exception {
    System.out.println("Here I am");
    // get subscribed mssg here
  } 
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
    // not needed
  }
  public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
    }
}
```

for more information refer [eclipse paho](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076616/)

FYI:

You will want to use the following details to connect an MQTT client to Adafruit IO:

```
**Host**: io.adafruit.com
**Port**: 1883 or 8883 (for SSL encrypted connection)
**Username**: your Adafruit account username (see the accounts.adafruit.com 
**Password**: your Adafruit IO key (click the AIO Key button on a dashboard 
 find the key)
 Adafruit IO's MQTT API exposes feed data using special topics.  You can 
 publish a new value for a feed to its topic, or you can subscribe to a 
 feed's topic to be notified when the feed has a new value. Anyone of the 
 following topic forms is valid for a feed:
 (username)/feeds/(feed name or key)
 (username)/f/(feed name or key)
```

Comment: Sir i have not familiar with MQTT please share proper code if u have

Comment: please refer the last link i have shared.If any doubts you can ask !

Comment: if not familiar with MQTT please download MQTT.fx and analyze how the data is sent.